# Finder does not show Xcode project icon properly after upgrade to Xcode 7

Tags: xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 7, and in Finder project icon become white icons, why? Pressing i.e. ClangFormat.xcodeproj will open Xcode, but still it is annoying. Earlier it was a blue like icon.

[image]

Comment: delete these cache folders and reboot : 
`/Library/Caches`  |  `/System/Library/Caches`  |  `/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/Library/Caches`

Comment: deleted them rebooted, but did not help

Comment: are you on Yosemite ?

Comment: yes I am on Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: download the cache cleaner from http://www.northernsoftworks.com/download.html 
open it go to Demo -> maintenance and clear all cache -> reboot, if this still doesn't work reinstall Xcode

Comment: You may also be able to do a Get Info on one of the files, change Open With to something else, then change it back to Xcode. I've had that fix this very issue (although with a different file type).